# Can't get CSP to work as intended in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, content-security-policy

I have a NextJS project and I am trying to set up the secure headers in my project next.config.js file.

I have tried many possibly delusions from the internet but had no luck.

I am trying to set the `Content-Security-Policy` header so only the necessary things are allowed. That would be style sheets, scripts, fonts from fonts.googleapi.com and images from my project's `public` folder.

But I can't get it to work. I have also tried setting the header to `default-src *`, but still, it just shows a website with no styles and no fonts.

I have copied the NextJS guide to this and had no luck. I am pretty lost and confused about how this works.

**index.js**

```
export default function Index() {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <>
            <Center h='100vh'>
                <Box display='flex' flexDirection='column' justifyContent='center'>
                    <Stack spacing='10'>
                        <Box display='inline-block' mx='auto'>
                            <Image w='75px' src="/logo.jpeg" alt="logo" />
                        </Box>
                        {/* Card */}
                        <Box w={['280px', '300px']} borderRadius='lg' border='1px' borderColor='gray.200' shadow='lg' p='6'>
                            <Box textAlign='center'>
                                <Heading size='lg'>
                                    Log in
                                </Heading>
                            </Box>
                            <Box my='6'>
                                <Divider />
                            </Box>
                            <Box>
                                <form>
                                    <Stack spacing='6'>
                                        <Box>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <FormLabel htmlFor="username">Username</FormLabel>
                                                <Input borderRadius='lg' type="text" id="username" />
                                            </FormControl>
                                        </Box>
                                        <Box>
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <FormLabel htmlFor="password">Password</FormLabel>
                                                <Input borderRadius='lg' type="password" id="password" />
                                            </FormControl>
                                        </Box>
                                        <Box>
                                            <Button w='100%' borderRadius='lg' colorScheme='green'>
                                                Log in
                                            </Button>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Stack>
                                </form>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </Stack>
                </Box>
            </Center>
        </>
    )
}
```

**next.config.js**

```
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self';
    child-src example.com;
    style-src 'self' example.com;
    font-src 'self'; 
`;

const securityHeaders = [
    {
        key: "X-Frame-Options",
        value: "deny"
    },
    {
        key: "X-Content-Type-Options",
        value: "nosniff"
    },
    {
        key: "Referrer-Policy",
        value: "strict-origin"
    },
    {
        key: "Strict-Transport-Security",
        value: "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    },
    {
        key: "X-XSS-Protection",
        value: "1; mode=block",
    },
    {
        key: "Permissions-Policy",
        value: "camera=(self); battery=(); geolocation=(); microphone=()"
    },
    {
        key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
        value: ContentSecurityPolicy.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim()
    }
];

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/:path*",
                headers: securityHeaders,
            },
        ]
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

**globals.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
```

**Chrome DevTools**
[image: Chrome DevTool CSP errors]

---

Errors after the answer from @tszhong0411
The errors I am getting now are from my service worker for my PWA app.

The red lines are my domain, but I reference them as `example.com`

[image: DEVTool for PWA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another way to set up CSP in Next.js. Just create `_middleware.ts` under pages.

`pages/_middleware.ts`

```js
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self';
    child-src example.com;
    style-src 'self' example.com;
    font-src 'self'; 
  `

  const response = NextResponse.next()

  response.headers.set('Content-Security-Policy', ContentSecurityPolicy.replace(/\n/g, ''))
  response.headers.set('X-Frame-Options', 'deny')
  response.headers.set('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
  response.headers.set('Referrer-Policy', 'strict-origin')
  response.headers.set('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload')
  response.headers.set('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block')
  response.headers.set('Permissions-Policy', 'camera=(self); battery=(); geolocation=(); microphone=()')

  return response
}
```

Comment: Will this still work if I didn't create my project as TypeScript?

Comment: Tried making a .js version, but getting some result

Comment: Oh, maybe I make a mistake. You can check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-g9qj1y?file=pages%2F_middleware.js) to solve it. Notice `script-src` should include 'unsafe-eval'. Also, the `Permissions-Policy` should use comma to separate it.

Comment: Yeah great, thanks. It looks like it works. But the last errors are from my service worker because my app is a PWA. I have updated my post with an image of the DevTools with the last errors.